# What does the notation $H=\{ a | a^2=e \}$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, notation

What is the meaning of notation $H=\{ a | a^2=e \}$? Is it  the same  as $H=\{a,a^2=e\}$?

(Here $a$ is an element of some group, with identity $e$.)

Comment: What?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: yea i know but its just H={a,(a^2)=e } is that what H is?

Comment: To reiterate: what?

Comment: so H={a s.t. $a^2$=e} means H={a,$a^2$}

Comment: If you keep reiterating the same thing, I'll keep reiterating "What?". So, what?

Comment: as in like that is what the notation means

Comment: use `|` or `\mid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see what you mean by $H=\{a,a^2=e\}$. In any case, the notation $H=\{a\mid a^2=e\}$ means the following (here I am assuming that $H$ is supposed to be a subset of some bigger set $X$, otherwise it makes no sense):

"H is the set containing all the elements $a\in X$ such that $a^2 = e$"

E.g., if $X=\mathbb R$ and $e$ denotes the identity element $e=1$, we will have that $H=\{-1,1\}$.

Edit: typo.